# Problems with get_gueryset method in Django

Tags: python, django, pagination

I have a problem with filtering a queryset that after filtering should be paginated, I am using get_queryset to filter the queryset of objects but on the page nothing is displayed. I have a blog page where I have all the post in a list, and are paginated, on the page I have the most common tags and whenever I click on a tag it redirects the user on the page with posts that have that tag and I want them to be displayed in a list and to be paginated like in the initial page but it's not working.

my view:

```
class TaggedPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/blog.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 2

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        tags = Post.tags.most_common()[:8]
        context['banner_page_title'] = 'Blog'
        context['page_location'] = 'home / blog'
        context['tags'] = tags
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
        return Post.objects.filter(tags=tag).order_by('-published_date')
```

model:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    class PostCategory(models.TextChoices):
        FAMILY = 'FAMILY', _('Family')
        BUSINESS  = 'BUSINESS', _('Business')
        MWRKETING = 'MARKETING', _('Marketing')
        SPENDINGS = 'SPENDINGS', _('Spendings')

    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=200, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(_('Content'))
    category = models.CharField(_('Category'), max_length=9, choices=PostCategory.choices, default=PostCategory.BUSINESS)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('Slug'), max_length=200, blank=True, null=False, unique=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(_('Tags'))
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Published Date/Time'), auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(_('Updated Date/Time'), auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def comments_count(self):
        return self.comments.count()
```

url:

```
path('tag/<slug:slug>/', TaggedPostListView.as_view(), name='tag'),
```

```
{% extends 'home/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <!--================Blog Area =================-->
    <section class="blog_area section-margin">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-8 mb-5 mb-lg-0">
                  <div class="blog_left_sidebar">
                    {% for post in posts %}
                      <article class="blog_item">
                        <div class="blog_item_img">
                          <img class="card-img rounded-0" src="{% static 'img/blog/m-blog-1.jpg' %}" alt="Post Image">
                          <a href="{% url 'post' post.slug %}" class="blog_item_date">
                            <h3>{{ post.published_date|date:"d" }}</h3>
                            <p>{{ post.published_date|date:"M" }}</p>
                          </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="blog_details">
                            <a class="d-inline-block" href="{% url 'post' post.slug %}">
                                <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
                            </a>
                            <p>{{ post.content|truncatechars:200 }}</p>
                            <ul class="blog-info-link">
                              <li><i class="ti-user"></i></li>
                              {% if post.comments_count %}
                              <li><i class="ti-comments"></i>{{ post.comments_count }} - Comments</li>
                              {% else %}
                                <li><i class="ti-comments"></i>0 Comments</li>
                              {% endif %}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                      </article>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% if is_paginated %}
                      <nav class="blog-pagination justify-content-center d-flex">
                        <ul class="pagination">
                        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                        <li class="page-item">
                            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" class="page-link" aria-label="Previous">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">
                                    <span class="ti-arrow-left"></span>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        {% endif %}

                        {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
                            {% if page_obj.number == num %}
                            <li class="page-item active">
                                <a href="?page={{ num }}" class="page-link">{{ num }}</a>
                            </li>
                            {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a href="?page={{ num }}" class="page-link">{{ num }}</a>
                            </li>
                            {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}

                        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                            <li class="page-item">
                                <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="page-link" aria-label="Next">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">
                                        <span class="ti-arrow-right"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        {% endif %}
                        </ul>
                      </nav>
                    {% endif %}
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4">
                  <div class="blog_right_sidebar">
                      <aside class="single_sidebar_widget search_widget">
                          <form action="#">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Keyword">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                  <button class="btn" type="button"><i class="ti-search"></i></button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <button class="button rounded-0 w-100" type="submit">Search</button>
                          </form>
                      </aside>

                      <aside class="single_sidebar_widget post_category_widget">
                        <h4 class="widget_title">Category</h4>
                        <ul class="list cat-list">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="d-flex">
                                    <p>Resaurant food</p>
                                    <p>(37)</p>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="d-flex">
                                    <p>Travel news</p>
                                    <p>(10)</p>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="d-flex">
                                    <p>Modern technology</p>
                                    <p>(03)</p>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="d-flex">
                                    <p>Product</p>
                                    <p>(11)</p>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="d-flex">
                                    <p>Inspiration</p>
                                    <p>21</p>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" class="d-flex">
                                    <p>Health Care (21)</p>
                                    <p>09</p>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                      </aside>

                      <aside class="single_sidebar_widget popular_post_widget">
                          <h3 class="widget_title">Recent Post</h3>
                          {% for post in recent_posts %}
                            <div class="media post_item">
                              <img src="img/blog/popular-post/post1.jpg" alt="post">
                              <div class="media-body">
                                  <a href="single-blog.html">
                                      <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
                                  </a>
                                  <p>{{ post.date_posted|date:"F m, Y" }}</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          {% endfor %}
                      </aside>
                      <aside class="single_sidebar_widget tag_cloud_widget">
                          <h4 class="widget_title">Post Tags</h4>
                          <ul class="list">
                              {% for tag in tags %}
                              <li>
                                  <a href="{% url 'tag' tag.slug %}">{{ tag }}</a>
                              </li>
                             {% endfor %}
                          </ul>
                      </aside>


                      <aside class="single_sidebar_widget instagram_feeds">
                        <h4 class="widget_title">Instagram Feeds</h4>
                        <ul class="instagram_row flex-wrap">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                  <img class="img-fluid" src="img/instagram/widget-i1.png" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                  <img class="img-fluid" src="img/instagram/widget-i2.png" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                  <img class="img-fluid" src="img/instagram/widget-i3.png" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                  <img class="img-fluid" src="img/instagram/widget-i4.png" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                  <img class="img-fluid" src="img/instagram/widget-i5.png" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                  <img class="img-fluid" src="img/instagram/widget-i6.png" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                      </aside>

                      <aside class="single_sidebar_widget newsletter_widget">
                        <h4 class="widget_title">Newsletter</h4>
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                          {% csrf_token %}
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="newsletter_email" placeholder="Enter email" required>
                          </div>
                          <button class="button rounded-0 w-100" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
                        </form>
                      </aside>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </section>
  <!--================Blog Area =================-->
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: How do you *render* the list?

Comment: I'll add the template now :D

Comment: I've added the rendering

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not `get_queryset`, the problem is that `get_context_data`, the method that is supposed to produce a dictionary that contains the context variables, no longer can work properly because you let it return an empty dictionary. You simply should override it, and add the items you want to pass to the template:

```
class TaggedPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/blog.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 2

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        tags = Post.tags.most_common()[:8]
        context['banner_page_title'] = 'Blog'
        context['page_location'] = 'home / blog'
        context['tags'] = tags
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
        return Post.objects.filter(tags=tag).order_by('-published_date')
```

In the template, you need to enumerate over the `page_obj` if you want to paginate, so:

```
{% for post in page_obj %}
    # …
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks you, now it's working properly, but it works without {% for post in page_obj %}

Comment: Should I change the enumaration of the post anyway?

Comment: @ARYAN: it will indeed work with `posts`, but then it will normally *not* paginate, so then you will get *all* `Post`s for that tag instead of the two for the given page.

Comment: Understood now :D